# What is the max number that you can take by 27 in 32 bits

Tags: math, computer-science, 32-bit

I am doing something in coding where it multiplies a number by from 1 to 27. I need to make a fail safe, where no number can be over this. Rounding to 2^32/2^64 would not work. It needs so be 32 bits so it can both support 32 and 64 bit OS's.

Comment: Also I'm on lua.

Comment: Signed or unsigned?

Comment: Unsigned. But, it is already solved.

Comment: You have indicated that your problem has been solved by accepting an answer. You shouldn't add 'Solved' to the title as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to multiply 3 by 5, but know the maximum allowed result is 10, you can easily tell that 3 is too large because 3 > 10/5. That’s all there’s to it :)

Since you insist on using a 32-bit type, and I assume your programming language is C, the maximum value `int32_t` can represent is `INT32_MAX` - those two come from `#include <stdint.h>`.

But you may be mistaken in your assumption about being limited to 32-bit types: `int64_t` works on most if not all major 32-bit platforms :)

Comment: I am using lua.

Comment: I used a similar code in lua: if tonumber(key) > (2^32/27-1) then
    print("\nInvalid key. Number too large.")
    GetMsgAndKey()
  end

Comment: Basically mine checks if it the number is over the max value (2^32/27-1) and then asks for a new number if it is.

Comment: The maximum value of a signed 32 bit integer is *not* 2^32! It is (2^31)-1. And the test should thus check against (((2^31)-1) / 27). Those parentheses are also important!

Comment: But lua defaults to representing all numbers as the `double` type, so you have to check what is the size of `double` on the underlying C platform that lua targets. On “big” systems like PCs, MACs, iOS and Android, a `double` is a 64-bit IEEE floating point representation and the test you propose is pointless. If the input number can be represented, then so can be the result of division by 27 (denormals may be problematic but that’s only a problem for extremely small numbers so you don’t expect to face it, I presume).

Answer (score 0):

`(2^32/27-1)` will not give you the correct upper value. As an integer it is 159072861 which is one too low.

The maximum integer value that can be stored in 32 bits is `2^32 - 1` which works out as 4294967295.

So the maximum value is actually `(2^32 - 1) // 27` which is 159072862.

Note the use of integer division which I assume is what you want.